hello i want to port 3D render to Blender
I know a friend of mine he build 3D renderer better then Corona.
How can I port that engine to Blender? By the way he built his engine into Lightwave3d and I told him about the idea he told me you need to find someone who can port it.
I want to learn how to port 3D engine render to Blender.

Sorry but this is a Q&A site to help with problems using Blender and its built-in addons so your question is off-topic here. There are no Blender developers here, nor does anyone here work for or have any association with the Blender Foundation.

so what this website is for?   if its not from blender fondation or  anyone can coder here !!what is the points ? for addon built in blender wich mean addon already built in blender by Blender fodation , or thirdparty . can you please  delete my account. i dont care if a blender coders here or not any coders can contribute on this new engine. tell me how i delete my account for not receiving any pm from this thnx in advance . take care of your self.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. You can request that your account be deleted here if you wish but deleting this question yourself will prevent you receiving any further contact about it.

I would try examining the internals of existing render engine add-ons, such as POV-Ray. Also, I found this page in the Blender Python API docs which could be helpful.
